# Recording Multiple Kinds Of Microphones In Reaper

Tags: microphone, reaper, input, usb, xlr-input

I've had a AT2020 USB mic for a while but I recently bought a Scarlett 2i2 and a MXL 990. Is it possible for me to record both microphones in Reaper? If so how? I know it'd be ideal to just get another xlr microphone and I will eventually, but for now I'd like to utilize what I have if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, I think, using Mac OS X's aggregate audio devices. Some advice on how these work and how you can set one up is found at the following links:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1215?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US
http://www.loopblog.net/tutorials/studio-and-gear/studio-techniques/use-multiple-audio-interfaces-on-mac-os-x/

The Reaper Blog says this is 'ok overall but not reliable enough for professional studio work' due to some latency and timing issues. Fair enough.

http://reaperblog.net/2013/01/using-multiple-audio-devices-in-reaper-osx/

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, [ASIO4all](http://www.asio4all.com/) might do it.

You can select ASIO4all as your audio device within Reaper, and then select multiple devices in ASIO4all's configuration, which will then look like a single device to Reaper. You'll then need to close and reopen Reaper's audio device configuration before you can choose which inputs / outputs Reaper will use.

I haven't tested this, so it's possible you might run into sync problems or something - worth a try though...